# Is this a good pattern regarding EclipseLink usage?

Tags: performance, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I have found the following pattern in a codebase that use EclipseLink through JPA:

```
TypedQuery query = ...
...
if(query.getResultList().size() > 0) {
  return query.getSingleResult();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Discarding the question about weither or not returning null is a good idea, I am more wondering about the fact that, although the two queries are consecutive in the code, under heavy load (which is expected on this project), the query could be fired twice against the database, rather than using the cache.

Am I wrong and can I safely assume that the second call will always hit the cache, or should this kind of pattern be reworked in order to catch the NoResultException instead?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just execute the query once and then return the  first value from the list?  The cache may prevent rebuilding the entities, but executing the query twice is unnecessary, and depending on the query and your options, will go to the database.

Comment: Well, this pattern might throw an NonUniqueResultException, while grabbing the first result will not, you have to do it by yourself. I am not saying it is a bad idea, I'm saying that I would rather have caught the NoResultException explicitly rather than doing this double call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a good pattern.  You are unnecessarily executing the query twice and so depending on other settings to prevent the query from hitting the database which may or may not have have been configured -EclipseLink has a query cache, but it is not enabled by default and you really don't need to use it here.  If you haven't configured a query cache, the entities will be cached from the first query, so you are reading in more than one entity into memory, and then potentially hitting the database again just to get one of those entities.

The common pattern is just to check the list and return the first value:

```
List values = query.getResultList();
if(values.size() > 0) {
  return values.get(0);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

If this query can return a high number of entities, you might also call query.setMaxResults(1); to limit the results returned.